# COALESCE working in only one case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, ssms, coalesce

I am trying to update an ERP software and I block on a syntax in a table made with PIVOTS

Let me explain, I would like in my table (which is functional) that all NULL values ​​be replaced by a 0.

In another table almost identical with the same syntax I succeeded but in the other, the COALESCEs do not work .. I'm stuck on it for quite some time. If someone can enlighten me ..

Here is the beginning of the code for the table where the COALESCE functions (I put only the beginning because the code makes 500 lines and the remainder remains the same)

```
DECLARE @VALEUR VARCHAR(10)

SET @VALEUR = RTRIM(CAST(:A_USER AS VARCHAR(10)))
          --Cette valeur va correspondre à l'id de la personne connectée
SET language us_english

DECLARE @P_A_USER VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @P_A_USER = VALEUR FROM T_PARAMETRE
WHERE PARAGRAPHE = 'COD_PRTDIRCOMM'



DECLARE @COD_GRP VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @COD_GRP = COD_GRP FROM USERS WHERE COD_USER = @VALEUR

IF @P_A_USER = 'GBL'
    BEGIN
    SET @P_A_USER = NULL
END

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'CA Total facturé' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge total (en €)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge total (en %)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'CA Exploitation facturé' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Exploitation (en €)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Exploitation (en %)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'CA Service facturé' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Service (en €)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Service (en %)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'CA Solution facturé' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Solution facturé (en €)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Marge Solution facturé (en %)' AS DONNEE) Q
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  -----------------------------------DEBUT TOTAL----------------------------     
   SELECT donnee,
          NUMLIGNE,
          COALESCE(january, 0)   AS JANUARY,
          COALESCE(february, 0)  AS FEBRUARY,
          COALESCE(march, 0)     AS MARCH,
          COALESCE(april, 0)     AS APRIL,
          COALESCE(may, 0)       AS MAY,
          COALESCE(june, 0)      AS JUNE,
          COALESCE(july, 0)      AS JULY,
          COALESCE(august, 0)    AS AUGUST,
          COALESCE(september, 0) AS SEPTEMBER,
          COALESCE(october, 0)   AS OCTOBER,
          COALESCE(november, 0)  AS NOVEMBER,
          COALESCE(december, 0)  AS DECEMBER
   FROM   (SELECT Datename(month, date_facture)   AS 'MOIS'
                  ,
                  Cast(Sum(n1)AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) AS
                  'CA_Total_mois',
                  'CA total facturé'    AS 'DONNEE',
                  'A'                             AS 'NUMLIGNE'
           FROM   v_facture
           WHERE  cod_com = ISNULL(@P_A_USER, cod_com)
                  AND Year(date_facture) = '2016'
           GROUP  BY Datename(month, date_facture)) AS ca_total_mois
          PIVOT(Sum(ca_total_mois)
               FOR mois IN (january,
                            february,
                            march,
                            april,
                            may,
                            june,
                            july,
                            august,
                            september,
                            october,
                            november,
                            december)) AS pvt1 
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------

   UNION ALL
   SELECT donnee,
          NUMLIGNE,
          COALESCE(january, 0)   AS JANUARY,
          COALESCE(february, 0)  AS FEBRUARY,
          COALESCE(march, 0)     AS MARCH,
          COALESCE(april, 0)     AS APRIL,
          COALESCE(may, 0)       AS MAY,
          COALESCE(june, 0)      AS JUNE,
          COALESCE(july, 0)      AS JULY,
          COALESCE(august, 0)    AS AUGUST,
          COALESCE(september, 0) AS SEPTEMBER,
          COALESCE(october, 0)   AS OCTOBER,
          COALESCE(november, 0)  AS NOVEMBER,
          COALESCE(december, 0)  AS DECEMBER
   FROM   (SELECT Datename(month, date_facture)   AS 'MOIS',
                  Cast(Sum(n2)AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) AS
                  'Marge_Total_mois',
                  'Marge total (en €)'       AS 'DONNEE',
                  'B'                             AS 'NUMLIGNE'
           FROM   v_facture
           WHERE  cod_com = ISNULL(@P_A_USER, cod_com)
                  AND Year(date_facture) = '2016'
           GROUP  BY Datename(month, date_facture)) AS
          Marge_Total_Mois
          PIVOT(Sum(marge_total_mois)
               FOR mois IN (january,
                            february,
                            march,
                            april,
                            may,
                            june,
                            july,
                            august,
                            september,
                            october,
                            november,
                            december)) AS pvt2
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    UNION ALL


-- Etc ...
--  The end :

) Q2
                ON Q2.donnee = Q.donnee
ORDER  BY NUMLIGNE ASC
```

Here is the table he refers to:
[1st TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLHnz.png)

And here is the code where the COALESCEs do not work:

```
DECLARE @VALEUR VARCHAR(10)

SET @VALEUR = RTRIM(CAST(:A_USER AS VARCHAR(10)))
          -- This value will match the id of the connected person

SET language us_english

DECLARE @P_A_USER VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @P_A_USER = VALEUR FROM T_PARAMETRE
WHERE PARAGRAPHE = 'COD_PRTDIRCOMM'



DECLARE @COD_GRP VARCHAR(10)
SELECT @COD_GRP = COD_GRP FROM USERS WHERE COD_USER = @VALEUR

IF @P_A_USER = 'GBL'
    BEGIN
    SET @P_A_USER = NULL
END

SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'Nouveaux contrats' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Contrats Renouvelés' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'RDV Réalisés' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'RDV Planifiés' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Nouveaux comptes ouverts' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Nouvelles affaires' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Nvl affaires avec exploitations' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'CA Nouvelles affaires (€)' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Affaires gagnées' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Affaires perdues' AS DONNEE
    UNION
    SELECT 'Taux affaires gagnées' AS DONNEE) Q
   LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  -----------------------------------DEBUT TOTAL----------------------------

   SELECT donnee,
          NUMLIGNE,
          COALESCE(january, 0)   AS JANUARY,
          COALESCE(february, 0)  AS FEBRUARY,
          COALESCE(march, 0)     AS MARCH,
          COALESCE(april, 0)     AS APRIL,
          COALESCE(may, 0)       AS MAY,
          COALESCE(june, 0)      AS JUNE,
          COALESCE(july, 0)      AS JULY,
          COALESCE(august, 0)    AS AUGUST,
          COALESCE(september, 0) AS SEPTEMBER,
          COALESCE(october, 0)   AS OCTOBER,
          COALESCE(november, 0)  AS NOVEMBER,
          COALESCE(december, 0)  AS DECEMBER
   FROM   (SELECT Datename(month, d1)   AS 'MOIS'
                  ,
                  Cast(Count(*)AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) AS
                  'Total_Nouveaux_Contrats',
                  'Nouveaux contrats'    AS 'DONNEE',
                  'A'                             AS 'NUMLIGNE'
           FROM   contrat
           WHERE  c22 = ISNULL(@P_A_USER, c22)
                  AND Month(D1)= MONTH(getdate())
                  AND  C27 = 'Nouveau contrat'
           GROUP  BY Datename(month, d1)) AS Total_Nouveaux_Contrats
          PIVOT(Sum(Total_Nouveaux_Contrats)
               FOR mois IN (january,
                            february,
                            march,
                            april,
                            may,
                            june,
                            july,
                            august,
                            september,
                            october,
                            november,
                            december)) AS pvt1 
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------

   UNION ALL
   SELECT donnee,
          NUMLIGNE,
          COALESCE(january, 0)   AS JANUARY,
          COALESCE(february, 0)  AS FEBRUARY,
          COALESCE(march, 0)     AS MARCH,
          COALESCE(april, 0)     AS APRIL,
          COALESCE(may, 0)       AS MAY,
          COALESCE(june, 0)      AS JUNE,
          COALESCE(july, 0)      AS JULY,
          COALESCE(august, 0)    AS AUGUST,
          COALESCE(september, 0) AS SEPTEMBER,
          COALESCE(october, 0)   AS OCTOBER,
          COALESCE(november, 0)  AS NOVEMBER,
          COALESCE(december, 0)  AS DECEMBER
   FROM   (SELECT Datename(month, d1)   AS 'MOIS',
                  Cast(Count(*)AS DECIMAL (18, 2)) AS
                  'Total_Contrats_Renouveles',
                  'Contrats Renouvelés'       AS 'DONNEE',
                  'B'                             AS 'NUMLIGNE'
           FROM   contrat
           WHERE  c22 = ISNULL(@P_A_USER, c22)
                  AND  Month(D1)= MONTH(getdate())
                  AND ( c27 = NULL
                        OR c27 = 'nouveau contrat' )
           GROUP  BY Datename(month, d1)) AS
          Total_Contrats_Renouveles
          PIVOT(Sum(Total_Contrats_Renouveles)
               FOR mois IN (january,
                            february,
                            march,
                            april,
                            may,
                            june,
                            july,
                            august,
                            september,
                            october,
                            november,
                            december)) AS pvt2
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------

    UNION ALL

 -- ETC ...

 -- La fin :

 ) Q2
                ON Q2.donnee = Q.donnee
ORDER  BY NUMLIGNE ASC
```

And here is the table it returns such a user for both for which there is not much value
[2nd TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5JxP.png)

I noticed that as long as there is a value in a row that is different from 0, then it will display all the other values ​​of that row that are null at 0 (the coalesces would work in this case there o_O)

So, sorry for the novel and thank you for your attention!

I am using SSMS for test my request but I use the code in the ERP software

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Product specific code there.)

Comment: I'am using SSMS

Comment: SSMS is not a dbms, you're using SQL Server properly. But seeing as coalesce "doesn't work" - that would indicate the value it's getting isn't NULL as you expect but might be empty string or something. So try to select the value itself without COALESCE and see what you get.

Comment: Ok sorry, I am not english I don't understand all of those terms. I get only NULL, but when it's null it shows nothing in my table, and I want a 0, like the first table, and when I delete the COALESCE in the first table, it return nothing. So I use the same COALESCE in the second with the same syntax but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I haven't much to go on here but it looks like a missing 's'. I think the COALESCE is working but the LEFT OUTER JOIN is not.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT 'Nouveaux contrats' AS DONNEE
    UNION
```

and later

```
WHERE  c22 = ISNULL(@P_A_USER, c22)
    AND  Month(D1)= MONTH(getdate())
    AND ( c27 = NULL
        OR c27 = 'nouveau contrat' )
GROUP  BY Datename(month, d1)) AS
```

Try including the name from both sides of the join to ensure the row is coming back at all.